# How do I select only the maximum value?

Tags: mysql

My query looks like this:

```
select e.cid, e.section,
sum(if(e.grade =  'd' or e.grade = 'f', 1, 0)) as count_fails,
sum(if(e.grade = 'a' or e.grade = 'b' or e.grade = 'c' , 1, 0)) as count_pass
from homework3.enrollment e
group by e.cid, e.section 
having max((count_fails/(count_fails + count_pass))*100);
```

What I am trying to do is return only the tuple which has the greatest percentage of failing. The above query is returning all tuples which have a value greater than 0 for the having condition.

I don't want to select the failure percentage because this is a subquery and I cannot have 3 operands.

Just to be absolutely clear, if this is my table, I want to only return the (336,1) tuple but without the percent_fail column.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: greatest percentage of passing or fail?

Comment: @forpas greatest % of failing which would be (336,1,100)

Comment: In your question you say: *I am trying to do is return only the tuple which has the greatest percentage of passing*

Comment: @forpas i fixed it, thank you

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand you correctly. You want obtain greatest percentage of passing or failing? If you want to return only the first tuple from given table u can us your query as a subquery and limit answer to only one: `SELECT cid, section FROM (your query) AS subquery LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Piotr I want to return the tuple with the greatest percentage of students failing but with only cid and section. I don't believe LIMIT would work because that is not telling it to select the tuple with the maximum percent_fail. In my original post in the code section the line that states `having max((count_fails/(count_fails + count_pass))*100)`is how I am trying to achieve this. But for whatever reason that is not working.

Comment: @PabloH as far I remember you cannot use computed value from sum() aggregate function in `HAVING` clause. You should probably compute it in `HAVING` clause as well. So to sum up, I think that you should compute your sum only in `HAVING` clause: `select e.cid, e.section from homework3.enrollment e
group by e.cid, e.section having max((if(e.grade =  'd' or e.grade = 'f', 1, 0) / if(e.grade =  'd' or e.grade = 'f', 1, 0) + if(e.grade = 'a' or e.grade = 'b' or e.grade = 'c' , 1, 0)) * 100)`. Let me know if it works :)

Comment: @Piotr So that ALMOST works - but it returns any tuple having a percent_fail greater than 0. (percent_fail being the value computed in the having statement)

Comment: @PabloH As I see my answer know, I think I forgot the value which should be compared with `max()`. Do you exactly know the maximum value? If yes, you should provide it `max() = value` , if no you should probably compute it in the subquery `max() = (select ... )`. Note that subquery with `SELECT` statement should returns only one value. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ORDER BY` clause with `LIMIT`:

```
select e.cid, e.section
from homework3.enrollment e
group by e.cid, e.section 
order by sum(e.grade in ('d', 'f')) / count(*) desc limit 1
```

For MySql 8.0+ use rank() window function:

```
select t.cid, t.section
from (
  select cid, section,
    rank() over(order by sum(grade in ('d', 'f')) / count(*) desc) rn
  from homework3.enrollment
  group by cid, section
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: But it only works fine if you don’t have more than one tuple with the same maximum percentage.

Comment: Not only what @Piotr said but this is a subquery and it seems mysql does not support limit in a subquery.

Comment: Does your version of MySql support window functions? 8.0+

Comment: @forpas Im on 8.0 but I dont know what you mean by window functions - I'm a student just learning mysql so apologies for my slowness.

Comment: See my 2nd query

Comment: @forpas that 2nd query is causing syntax errors in mysql - also we haven't learned rank or over in my class quite yet so we wouldn't be able to use that unforunately.

Comment: There are no syntax errors as you can see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/j5kRk7gxJhNBhBsYTapCGA/1 if you are using MySql 8.0